# How to mock method with ViewModel in MVC4 with Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to test the following method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var transactions = db.Transactions.Include(t => t.User)
                            .GroupBy(t => t.UserId)
                            .Select(group => new TransactionViewModel
                            {
                                User = group.FirstOrDefault().User.FullName,
                                UserId = group.FirstOrDefault().UserId,
                                Total = (group.Sum(t => t.TransactionAmount))
                            });

    // Show lowest balance first
    return View(transactions.ToList());
}
```

Here the `Transaction` model has a list of `Orders`, has a foreign key to `User` and some more properties, see:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The `TransactionViewModel` looks as follows:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

and is used to calculate the `Total` of different transactions belonging to a user.

To test this method I have a `FakeDbSet` and use a `FakeContext` (which both work in tests of other controllers) in the following Setup:

```
[TestClass]
public class TransactionControllerTest
{
    TransactionController trController;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TransactionControllerTestInitialize()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var memoryTransactionItems = new FakeDbSet<Transaction>
        {
           new Transaction {
               Date = DateTime.Today,
               TransactionAmount = 5.10M,
               UserId = 1,
               Orders = new List<Order>{
                    // Categorie 2 and confirmed
                    new Order { OrderId = 2, 
                                UnitPrice = 2.00M, 
                                Quantity = 1, 
                                Date = DateTime.Today, 
                                IsConfirmed = true, 
                                User = new User { 
                                    Name = "Kees", 
                                    FullName="Kees Piet", 
                                    Email = "Kees@DeHond.nl", 
                                    isAvailable = true, 
                                    UserId = 1 
                                }, 
                                Product = new Product {
                                    Category = new Category {
                                        CategoryId = 2, 
                                        Name = "Categorie2"
                                    }, 
                                    Name = "Testproduct2",
                                    Price = 2.00M,
                                    Visible = true
                                }
                    },
                    // Categorie 2 and confirmed
                    new Order { OrderId = 2, 
                                UnitPrice = 1.00M, 
                                Quantity = 1, 
                                Date = DateTime.Today, 
                                IsConfirmed = true, 
                                User = new User { 
                                    Name = "Jan", 
                                    FullName="Jan Piet", 
                                    Email = "Jan@DeBouvrier.de", 
                                    isAvailable = true, 
                                    UserId = 2 
                                }, 
                                Product = new Product {
                                    Category = new Category {
                                        CategoryId = 2, 
                                        Name = "Categorie2"
                                    }, 
                                    Name = "Testproduct2",
                                    Price = 3.10M,
                                    Visible = true
                                }
                    }
               }
           }
        };


        // Create mock units of work
        var mockData = new Mock<FakeContext>();
        mockData.Setup(m => m.Transactions).Returns(memoryTransactionItems);

        // Setup controller
        trController = new TransactionController(mockData.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTransactionIndex()
    {
        // Invoke
        var viewResult = trController.Index() as ViewResult;
        var transactionsFromView = (IEnumerable<TransactionViewModel>)viewResult.Model;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, transactionsFromView.Count(),
            "The amount of transactions added to the Index View should be 1.");
    }
}
```

When I run the `TestTransactionIndex` I get the following error:

> Test Name:    TestTransactionIndex Test Outcome:  Failed Test
>   Duration: 0:00:30.6276475
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>   Tests.Controllers.TransactionControllerTest.TestTransactionIndex threw
>   exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. Result StackTrace:   at lambda_method(Closure
>   , IGrouping`2 )    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Controllers.TransactionController.Index()

I find this strange since I setup my mock units in the proper way. I hope someone can explain how I can properly send the `FakeDbSet<Transaction>` to the view and not get a `NullReferenceException`.

/Edit As requested, here are the contructors for `TransactionController`:

```
private IContext _context;

public TransactionController()
{
    _context = new Context();
}

public TransactionController(IContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the constructors from TransactionController

Comment: @user1511384 Yes. Done.

Comment: In your index method you have `db.Transactions.Include(t => t.User)`, have you tried configuring the fake context with a fake dbSet of users? Because the select has this line `User = group.FirstOrDefault().User.FullName,` that will give a null reference if _User_ is null. Something like `mockData.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(....)` If that doesn't work you could try populating the User property in your fake transactions

Comment: Thanks Daniel that is indeed the issue.

Comment: Cool @user2609980, let me post that as an answer so you can accept it. You just configured a fake users dbSet?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. yes I did. Other method this was not enough yet though. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in your index method includes the line:

```
db.Transactions.Include(t => t.User)
```

And the **Select** part of the query is using the `User` property in the `Transaction` class to populate the `TransactionViewModel` as in

```
User = group.FirstOrDefault().User.FullName,
```

That line will throw a **NullReferenceException** if the User property in the Transaction is null. So you need the result of that query to contain a not null User property when executed in your unit test using the fake objects.

I am not sure how your fake context and DbSets work, but the easiest thing to try is to populate the User property of the Transactions in your fake `memoryTransactionItems`.

You may also try adding a fake users dbset as in the next code snippet (I'm assuming you have a Users DbSet in your EF context):

```
var memoryUsers = new FakeDbSet<User>
{
    new User{ UserId = 1, ... },
    ...
};

mockData.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(memoryUsers);
```